# AngularJS ng-repeat and scope populated within http call results in empty html elements

Tags: angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat, unordered

I have defined an array within scope:

```
$scope.foo = [];
```

I then make a $http call, and populate that variable from the success event in my controller.

In the template i have an unordered list as such:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="i in foo">{{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

The outcome is an unordered list that has as many li elements as $scope.foo, but the contents of it are empty:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope"></li>
<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope"></li>
<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope"></li>
.
.
.
```

I can see that the array has been populated. Furthermore the LI element count matches the array length (as expected), but **the contents of the LI are empty**.

All documentation i can find looks like this for populating an unordered list. I previously changed it from a jQuery call to an angular $http.post call since some problems with scoping would arise from that.

Why are the contents of the li elements empty?

Comment: what is the structure of your `foo` object that's being fetched?

Comment: It is a flat array of strings. This is supposed to be a pagination template.

Comment: Can you update the post with the http part where you are updating the foo? Have you tried $apply?

Comment: @sm0ke21 Just a question, I see your second code snippet says `i in range` instead of `i in foo`?

Comment: That is a typo. thanks.

Comment: @sm0ke21 can you add the code where you set the `$scope.foo` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made $scope.foo = []; then use foo not range.

Example:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope">{{i}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope" ng-bind="i"></li>
```

Edited to fix my mistake, thanks for tip.

Comment: You just used the code the question used `<li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope">{{i}}</li>`

Comment: Lol I am blind or what :D
Still there is $scope.foo but call in ng-repeat goes to $scope.range

Comment: Your suggestion seems to do the trick. I am trying to apply this to this template but i am getting the same result: <li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope"><a href="#">{{i}}</a></li>.

Comment: Other tip, try this:

`ng-repeat="i in foo track by $index" ng-bind="foo[$index]"`

once it fixed some problem at one of my apps.

Comment: @PawełSmołka just to prove you don't need to add `ng-bind` http://jsfiddle.net/rse0xhqr/1/

Comment: Thanks Tjaart. I was able to do this by using <li ng-repeat="i in foo" class="ng-scope"><a ng-click="updatePage(i)" href="#" ng-bind="i"></a></li>. Still have a lot to learn. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tjaart van der Walt 
I agree you do not need. Still I have found some situations where it is better to work with ng-bind and work on array[$index] than on 'element in array'.
While it seems same it is not, especially when you try to use ng-change="element" or ng-change="array[$index]".